# How to use stroph.js server-side in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp, strophe

Anyone successfully used stroph.js server-side? http://strophe.im/strophejs/

I'd like to use the Connection object for prebinding XMPP sessions.

I cant get [node-xmpp-client](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-client) to do prebinding and trying to find alternatives.

Comment: Take a look at node-bosh-xmpp-client (on Github) from @eelcocramer. I've been using it and it works well. There's an open pull request from me which adds HTTPS support.

Comment: Thanks! Wow conversejs in the digital flesh! I ended up switching from Openfire to prosody and all my problems were solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with using Openfire as my XMPP server with node-XMPP-client. I didn't have any BOSH prebinding problems with node-XMPP-client when I switched to prosody.